# php cookies and browser not sending cookie to server

Tags: php, cookies

So I have a problem where this doesn't work.. the cookie file named "Main" exists in browser cache, but when I try the below code nothing is collected from it.

```
 if (isset($_COOKIE["Main"])){
 $user_cookie = $_COOKIE["Main"];
 }
```

Further digging shows I have another cookie for the same domain name that is part of a wikibridge...

both cookies have the same contents.. a username "John" exactly.

when I try

```
var_dump($_COOKIE); exit;
```

I get a bunch of array data, collected from the cookies my browser sends back, but it seems my browser firefox is not sending the "Main" cookie backm, its only sending a bunch of other cookies all part of the same domain name.

So despite this $_COOKIE["Main"] existing, it never gets sent back to the server for php to get it contents.

HELP

Comment: What is setting this Main cookie, what is it's meta-info (path, domain, expire, etc), and how are you accessing this script?

Comment: hmm I checked seems there is some differences... the "Main" coookie has this....  Host: Website  Path: /forum/     ....and the "Wiki" cookie has this .... Host: .Website   Path: /      so there does seem to be some differences... ps wish stackoverflow would get less crap ways of replying and being able to use better formatting.

Comment: Use `@` to reply and http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting. To fix your problem set the path correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons for cookies of same domain not being sent.

First, I would check to see if the cookie is set as a secure cookie which is only sent for https requests.

Second, I would check if the cookie has a specific path that it is set to be active for and your request is not part of that path.

Comment: Yeh it seems the cookie I want has a Path: /forum  .. that's a bit annoying as I set that cookie while its accessed from the forum.... how can I make it set that cookie to the root like /

Comment: In that forum where the cookie is set, just set the path as `/`.

Comment: Thanks.. had no idea I wasn't setting the path to "/"   it works now and is sending the cookie.

Comment: @MikeBrant THANK YOU! I have been trying for 2 solid days to get the PHP 5.4+ file upload $_SESSION value working using http ...and I have been working with https so long on our site that the setcookie secure=true setting has been there forever. I noticed the browser wasn't sending cookies, did a quick search and found this. I read your comment above, changed the value to false and hey presto - problem solved! Thank you again.